# Editable Dialog Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm starting in primefaces and I'm trying create a editable dialog for my datatable. When I clik in the edit button (footer of datatable), the dialog appears, but dont show the values of the selected row. What's wrong?

my xhtml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./../WEB-INF/template_sistema.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form prependId="false">  

                    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="resultadoBanescap" value="#{lstResultados.resultadoBanescap}"  
                                 paginator="true" rows="10"  
                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20"
                                 emptyMessage="Não foram encontradas informações"
                                 selection="#{resultadoBanescap.selecionado}" selectionMode="single">  

                        <p:column id="colunaNumero" 
                                  filterBy="#{resultadoBanescap.rbcnr}" 
                                  sortBy="#{resultadoBanescap.rbcnr}" 
                                  filterMatchMode="contains">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Número" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{resultadoBanescap.rbcnr}" />  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column id="colunaDia" 
                                  filterBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcdd}" 
                                  sortBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcdd}" 
                                  filterMatchMode="contains">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Dia" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcdd}" />  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column id="colunaMes" 
                                  filterBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcmm}" 
                                  sortBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcmm}" 
                                  filterMatchMode="contains">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Mês" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcmm}" />  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column id="colunaAno" 
                                  filterBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcaa}" 
                                  sortBy="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcaa}" 
                                  filterMatchMode="contains">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Ano" />  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <h:outputText value="#{resultadoBanescap.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcaa}" />  
                        </p:column> 

                        <f:facet name="footer">  
                            <p:commandButton id="viewButton" 
                                             value="View"  
                                             update=":form:dataTable" 
                                             oncomplete="detalheDialog.show()"
                                             onclick="detalheDialog.show()"/>  
                        </f:facet> 

                    </p:dataTable>  

                    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Detalhes" widgetVar="detalheDialog" resizable="false"  
                              width="300" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" modal="true" appendToBody="true">  

                        <h:form id="frmUpdate">
                            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
                                <h:outputText value="Número:" />  
                                <h:inputText value="#{lstResultados.selecionado.rbcnr}" />  

                                <h:outputText value="Dia:" />  
                                <h:inputText value="#{lstResultados.selecionado.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcdd}" />  

                                <h:outputText value="Mês:" />  
                                <h:inputText value="#{lstResultados.selecionado.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcmm}" />  

                                <h:outputText value="Ano:" />  
                                <h:inputText value="#{lstResultados.selecionado.tbResultadoBanescapPK.rbcaa}" />  
                            </h:panelGrid>  
                        </h:form>
                    </p:dialog>  

                </h:form>  
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

my bean file:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.banestes.ui.bean;

import br.com.banestes.domain.TbResultadoBanescap;
import br.com.banestes.domain.controller.TbResultadoBanescapJpaController;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author 030072182
 */
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "lstResultados")
public class ListResultados {

    private List<TbResultadoBanescap> resultadoBanescap;
    private TbResultadoBanescap selecionado;

    public ListResultados() {
        TbResultadoBanescapJpaController ctrl = new TbResultadoBanescapJpaController();
        resultadoBanescap = ctrl.findTbResultadoBanescapEntities();
    }

    public List<TbResultadoBanescap> getResultadoBanescap()
    {
        return resultadoBanescap;
    }

    public TbResultadoBanescap getSelecionado() {
        return selecionado;
    }

    public void setSelecionado(TbResultadoBanescap selecionado) {
        this.selecionado = selecionado;
    }


}
```

Another question is: is possible create one form in another xhtml and use he in the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. The selected row is not shown in the dialog because the dialog is not updated when the button in your footer is clicked. Your update should be `update=":form:dataTable :dialog"`.
2. Unless you're doing something with the data on the datatable (I don't see it in your code), you should remove `:form:dataTable` from your update as well.
3. In your `<p:dataTable>`, you are putting the selected data into `resultadoBanescap.selecionado`. However, in your dialog, you're reading data from `lstResultados.selecionado`. Check the logic.
4. You should bring your dialog out of the first form.
5. Yes, it's possible to create a form in another xhtml file and then use `<ui:include>` to add it to the dialog.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, I will verify your listed itens.

Comment: No work. Now he pass in the setSelecionado method (not performed before), but after that the dialog is showed.